# Elegant rotating logging filename in django

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to set up a logger that writes to a new file every day. I would like to log to a file in /log/name_YYYY_mm_dd.log but it seems that this is done initially.

Is there any elegant way to rotate the filename?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s|%(asctime)s|%(module)s|%(process)d|%(thread)d|%(message)s',
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'default': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'django_%s.log' % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M'))),
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'sensible': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You forgot `'when': 'midnight',` and possibly a wrapper if you log from [multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840785/timedrotatingfilehandler-doesnt-work-fine-in-django-with-multi-instance). Try [this](https://gist.github.com/JasonGiedymin/887364):

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s|%(asctime)s|%(module)s|%(process)d|%(thread)d|%(message)s',
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'default': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'django.log'),
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'when': 'midnight',
        'backupCount': '30',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'sensible': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

> The system will save old log files by appending extensions to the
>   filename. The extensions are date-and-time based, using the strftime
>   format `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` or [a leading portion thereof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler), depending on
>   the rollover interval.

Comment: Where would we get all these logging feature like `when` and others? Please provide links. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Django logging is just a thin wrapper of the Python logging module, you can use that to override Django settings if needed.

[Rotating logs in Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/):

```
import logging
import time

from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_timed_rotating_log(path):
    """"""
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                       when="midnight",
                                       interval=1,
                                       backupCount=5)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    for i in range(6):
        logger.info("This is a test!")
        time.sleep(75)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file = "timed_test.log"
    create_timed_rotating_log(log_file)
```

Bypassing Django might also avoid [parent loggers not receiving events from disabled children](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2015/01/27/Django-Logging-Configuration-logging_config-default-settings-logger/).

Comment: TimedRotatingFileHandler really helps!