# Log files get truncated with TimedRotatingFileHandler and Django

Tags: python, django, logging, mod-wsgi

I have log handlers configured to rotate at midnight:

```
'request_handler': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'when': 'midnight',
        'interval': 1,
        'filename':  os.path.join(LOG_ROOT, 'django_request.log'),
        'backupCount': 30,
        'formatter': 'standard',
        },
```

Also have cron job to archive/purge logs with command, which runs at 01:00 every day (crontab -e -> "0 1 * * * /cronscripts/archive_logs.sh"):

```
gzip --quiet *\.log\.[0-9]*
find $LOGS_DIR -mtime +$LOGS_KEEP_DAYS -exec rm {} \;
```

With that configuration log files get truncated by some reason, here description:

1. Rotated log django_request.log.2014-09-30 will have records from 00:00 to ~2:30 (the end time can vary a bit)
2. Meanwhile django_request.log before rotation has records after 02:30
3. django_request.log.2014-09-30 file has records dated 1-th of Oct instead of 30-th of Sep

Example:

```
alex@localhost$ tail django_request.log.2014-09-30
2014-10-01 02:02:48,562 [WARNING] django.request: Not Found: /admin_media/i...
```

Are there any ideas what's wrong? Django is running with apache/mod_wsgi.

Comment: Are multiple processes writing to the logs? Perhaps the solution to the following question would work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840785/timedrotatingfilehandler-doesnt-work-fine-in-django-with-multi-instance

Comment: Yes, there are several apache processes accessing logs. Will try the solution, thanks!

Comment: You are right - using log locking solved the problem, thanks!